# How to deploy a NextJS 13 app using App Router in cPanel?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have the commitment to upload an application that is with NextJS 13 to cPanel. I've already tried everything but nothing works. The NextJS documentation regarding deployments on platforms other than Vercel is very unfortunate and I really need help getting that app up. I am using App Router and I have tried to do the deployment by adding the server.js file but that solution does not apply for nextJS working with App Router. I have not been able to find information about how to upload an app like this.

Docs on my project

[image]

I tried to apply the solution of adding the server.js file and changing the scripts in the package.json but that will not be working for me since I am using App Router. No tutorial works for me because everyone uses vercel and I need to use cPanel.

Comment: maybe this help you: https://medium.com/@geevadon/how-to-deploy-a-next-js-app-on-cpanel-efficiently-c00c5eb860de

Comment: It is important that your cpanel provide **Node App** software in the Software section. this means that you can have a node app such as node.js or next.js. You should know that **Next.js** should run as a node application. After that you can use this [link](https://medium.com/@geevadon/how-to-deploy-a-next-js-app-on-cpanel-efficiently-c00c5eb860de)

Comment: In cpanel I have other node projects, so if it works. But it happens that with this when following the steps of the tutorial that you sent, the page never loads. It always gives me the following error:


forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I think it is because I am using App Router and not Page Router.

Also when I go to the cPanel error box it shows me this error:

Cannot serve directory [Here my path directory] No matching DirectoryIndex.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and asked Vercel to make the docs clearer about that.
In case you would like to follow the issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/53159

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same problem!

Comment: Thanks, I am facing the same problem. If you find any solution you're welcome!

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a general outline of the process:

Step 1: Begin by setting up a custom Next.js server. You need a server.js file in your project's root directory, populated with the needed code. Look up an official Next.js guide for help.

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const hostname = 'localhost'
const port = 3000
// when using middleware `hostname` and `port` must be provided below
const app = next({ dev, hostname, port })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()
app.prepare().then(() => {
createServer(async (req, res) => {
try {
// Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
// This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl
if (pathname === '/a') {
await app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
} else if (pathname === '/b') {
await app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
} else {
await handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
}
} catch (err) {
console.error('Error occurred handling', req.url, err)
res.statusCode = 500
res.end('internal server error')
}
})
.once('error', (err) => {
console.error(err)
process.exit(1)
})
 .listen(port, () => {
console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`)
})
})
```

Step 2: Tweak the package.json file. This step makes the environment ‘production-ready' and activates the server.js file.

```
{
"scripts": {
"start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it only works using "Pages Router", but not "App Router" as the question said. If you have a solution using "App Router" you're welcome because I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, it's preferable to adopt a static development approach. Modify your configuration within the `next.config` file by setting `"output"` to `"export"`. This is the strategy I employ on my website, abassdev.com. If you're utilizing dynamic routing, make sure to export `generateStaticParams()` in your pages. However, a drawback arises when fetching data from an API. In such cases, you'll have to rebuild and deploy whenever your incoming data changes. Alternatively, you can sidestep dynamic routing, opting for a React hook with a client-server setup. This way, you won't need to rebuild and deploy your site every time your database undergoes changes.